# Insert values into columns without NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I`m trying to calculate count of some values in data frame like

```
user_id  event_type
    1         a   
    1         a  
    1         b
    2         a
    2         b
    2         c
```

and I want to get table like

```
user_id  event_type  event_type_a  event_type_b  event_type_c
    1         a           2              1             0
    1         a           2              1             0
    1         b           2              1             0
    2         a           1              1             1
    2         b           1              1             1
    2         c           1              1             1
```

I`ve tried code like

```
df[' event_type_a'] = df['user_id', 'event_type'].where(df['event_type']=='a').groupby([user_id]).count()
```

and get table like

```
user_id    count_a
   1          2
   2          1
```

How i should insert this values into default df, to fill all rows without NaN items?

Maybe exsists method like, for exaple, `"insert into df_1['column'] from df_2['column'] where df_1['user_id'] == df_1['user_id'] "`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) for new columns names and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df2 = pd.crosstab(df['user_id'],df['event_type'])
#alternatives
#df2 = df.groupby(['user_id','event_type']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
#df2 = df.pivot_table(index='user_id', columns='event_type', fill_value=0, aggfunc='size')

df = df.join(df2.add_prefix('event_type_'), on='user_id')
print (df)
   user_id event_type  event_type_a  event_type_b  event_type_c
0        1          a             2             1             0
1        1          a             2             1             0
2        1          b             2             1             0
3        2          a             1             1             1
4        2          b             1             1             1
5        2          c             1             1             1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Never used crosstab in pandas before)

Comment: You still impress me with your speed. Very often I will formulate how I should solve the problem to see you have already :D

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way for getting df2 as Jez mentioned but slightly different , since I using the `transform` and did not provide the `agg` format , So the df2 shape has the same length as original df

```
df2= df.set_index('user_id').event_type.str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).transform('sum')
df2
Out[11]: 
         a  b  c
user_id         
1        2  1  0
1        2  1  0
1        2  1  0
2        1  1  1
2        1  1  1
2        1  1  1
```

---

Then using `concat`

```
df2.index=df.index
pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1)
Out[19]: 
   user_id event_type  a  b  c
0        1          a  2  1  0
1        1          a  2  1  0
2        1          b  2  1  0
3        2          a  1  1  1
4        2          b  1  1  1
5        2          c  1  1  1
```

Comment: Idea `df = pd.concat([df,df2.set_index(df.index)],axis=1)`